# how do I take selection from my php drop down list and turn it into a variable?

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to take a drop down box in PHP and select one item from the first box.  I then want the selected item from my first drop down box, and placed it into my $lineIDSelection variable so that I can insert it into a query for the next drop down box.  The main thing I am trying to get past is when I click on one of my options in the drop down box, I need to be able to submit it, or better yet, have it dynamically update to a variable.  here is a piece of the code I am working with.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("could not connect to the databse!");

$select_db = mysql_select_db('camdb') or die ('could not select camdb database!!');

    $lineID = "SELECT * FROM camTable;";
    $IDresult = mysql_query($lineID);

            echo"line" . "<br/>";
            echo "<select name=\"line\">";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($IDresult)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['line'] . "'>" . $row['line'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";



    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Length FROM camTable;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);      

            echo"Cam Length" . "<br/>";
            echo "<select name=\"Length\">";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['Length'] . "'>" . $row['Length'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>" . "<br/>" ."<br/>";
```

Comment: Explain your exact scenario what you are trying to do in two drop-down?? I think you will some more better and efficient way to do it.

Comment: 1) where do you want to use `$lineIDSelection` variable ? it is not mention in your code . 2) Your want to select value from one dropdown and on the basis of first dropdown value do you want to display your second drop-down option? please clarify it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is narrow down my next drod down list.  I have a table with 8 columns.  I want to click on line number in the first column and then insert that number into the query that populates my second drop down list to only show the "Length"(which is what the second drop down list is displaying) That has a column (Line) that matches.  so every time you go through another drop down box and select an option, the next drop down box will become smaller because it will only show the options from the data base where the previous selection is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Q.I then want the selected item from my first drop down box, and placed it into 
my $lineIDSelection variable so that I can insert it into a query for the next 
drop down box
```

See you can achieve this by Ajax:-

On-change on first drop-down you get value and on the basis of first drop-down 
       value you can generate second drop-down.

PHP:- assign id to drop-down

```
 echo "<select name='line' id='dropDown1'>";
```

Jquery :-

```
$('#dropDown1').change(function() {    
    var sel_item=$(this).val();
     // sel_item is first dropdown selected value.
     // pass it to ajax request 
         // in you ajax request get sel_item and assign it to $lineIDSelection


});
```

Comment: OK, I am trying to work through this, but I am getting a bit above my head.  I hate to have to be spoon fed, but I am not getting anywhere with this, I tried to go the jquery route, but I have never gotten into jquery before.  I guess I should have started out from the beginning saying that this is the first Programing project I have done.  It just seems like there would be a simple way to click on my value in the PHP dropdown box and be able to set that value to a php variable to place in my next query.  I appreciate any help I can get.